# Does Classical Latin have "lilies prolepsis"?

Tags: classical-latin, greek, syntax

There's a particular type of prolepsis in Greek which is often called "lilies prolepsis" because of the most famous example:

> καταμάθετε τὰ κρίνα τοῦ ἀγροῦ πῶς αὐξάνουσιν
>   Consider the lilies of the field, how they grow
>   (Matthew 6.24)

This occurs as far back as Homer:

> ᾔδεε γὰρ κατὰ θυμὸν ἀδελφεὸν ὡς ἐπονεῖτο
>   For he knew in his mind his brother, how he was troubled
>   (Iliad 2.409)

And even appears occasionally in English:

> [I] watch'd him, how he singled Clifford forth
>   (Shakespeare, Henry VI II.1.12)

*(Examples from Fraser, [Consider the lilies: prolepsis and the development of complementation](https://www.repository.cam.ac.uk/bitstream/handle/1810/198282/Prolepsis.pdf?sequence=1).)*

Does this sort of prolepsis ever appear in native, Classical Latin (as opposed to the Greek-influenced Latin of the Vulgate)? Is it attested in prose or poetry, or both?

Comment: Interesting -- I'd never heard this called "lilies prolepsis". In case it's useful, in transformational syntactic terms this is an instance of subject-to-object raising.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cicero, *Ad familiares* 8.10.3:

> *nosti Marcellum, quam tardus et parum efficax sit, itemque Servium, quam cunctator.*
>   'You know Marcus, how slow he is and how ineffective, and likewise Servius, what a dawdler he is.'