# Constituendi autem sunt qui sint in amicitia fines et quasi termini diligendi (Cic. Amic. 56)

Tags: classical-latin, syntax, agreement, interrogative

I was wondering to what extent the agreement pattern exemplified with the following sentences drawn from Cicero's *De Amicitia* can be regarded as the most natural one. I'm asking this question since, for example, in my native language (Catalan), one would expect singular agreement here (cf. *constituendum est*), the indirect interrogative subordinate clause being its neuter singular subject. However, it seems that the attraction pattern exemplified below could be claimed to be the most natural one here. Is this true?

> **Constituendi** autem **sunt** qui sint in amicitia fines et quasi termini diligendi (Cic. *Amic.* 56)

> Quidam saepe in parva pecunia **perspiciuntur** quam sint leves; quidam, quos parva movere non potuit, cognoscuntur in magna. (Cic. *Amic.* 63).

---

**EDIT I**

Ben Kovitz's example *Perspicio **te**, Miles Gloriose, quam levis sis*, which involves an instantiation of the so-called [**proleptic accusative**](https://www.degruyter.com/view/journals/joll/2/1/article-p87.xml?language=en), is really illuminating. This construction could well be at the basis of the passive construction of the example above *Quidam saepe in parva pecunia perspiciuntur quam sint leves*: i.e., its nominative subject *quidam* could correspond to a subjacent proleptic accusative object in the active voice. Cf. also these interesting examples from Cicero & Terentius, respectively: *nosti uirum quam tectus* (Cic. *Att.* 14.21.2); *patrem nouisti ad has res quam sit perspicax* (Ter. *Haut.* 370).

---

**EDIT II**

Informally speaking, it seems that the two sentences above involve a sort of blending of two different syntactic structures:

(1) *Constituendi sunt fines* & (2) *constituendum est qui sint in amicitia fines*;

(1) *Quidam saepe in parva pecunia perspiciuntur* & (2) *Perspicitur quam (quidam) sint leves*.

**Is there any other alternative to this blending?** (see Ben Kovitz's skeptical comment below: there is "no need for unusual blending").

Cf. also the following parallelisms:

*Constituendi autem sunt (...) in amicitia fines* (Cic. *Amic.* 56) // *Alius igitur finis verae amicitiae constituendus est* (Cic. *Amic.* 59).

*Quidam saepe in parva pecunia perspiciuntur (...)* // *quidam (...) cognoscuntur in magna*. (Cic. *Amic*. 63).

Answer (score 6):

As I understand the first sentence, its subject is **qui** (together with the phrase after *et*), which is plural, referring to **fines**; **constituendi** is an adjective agreeing with that. Cutting out most of the sentence leaves:

> Constituendi sunt fines.

In English, putting the subject first, we might say:

> **What** in friendship are the **limits**, **are** to be established, and, in a way, the boundaries of affection.

In more natural English:

> We must now establish the limits of friendship and the boundaries of affection.

---

As I understand the second sentence (before the semicolon), its subject is plural **quidam**, agreeing with **perspiciuntur**. How does **quam sint leves** relate to **perspiciuntur**? A naïve literal translation into (ungrammatical) English might go:

> Some people, often involved with a small amount of money, are seen what lightweights they are.

That does sound to me like syntax I've seen from non-native speakers, especially those from Romance languages.

[Note 2 of §395](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/double-accusatives) in A&G seems to have the answer: **quam sint leves** is a secondary object:

> The secondary object may be retained with a passive verb.
>
> Belgae Rhēnum trāductī sunt. (B.G. 2.4)
> The Belgians were led over the Rhine.

Could we reconstruct the sentence in the active voice?

> Perspicio te, Miles Gloriose, quam levis sis.

If **perspicio** can take a secondary object like that, then this might be your answer.

Comment: I agree with you that if we “cut out most of the sentence”, the main idea that remains is _Constituendi sunt fines_. I’m not sure what you mean when saying “As I understand the first sentence, its subject is _qui_.” I could be wrong but it seems to me that the sentence in the title involves a sort of blending of two different syntactic structures: (i) _constituendi sunt fines_ & (ii) _constituendum est qui sint fines_.

Comment: Your example _Perspicio te, Miles Gloriose, quam levis sis_ is very interesting. In my opinion, this example would also involve a blending of two different structures: (i) _Perspicio te_ & (ii) _Perspicio quam levis (tu) sis_.

Comment: Your example _Perspicio **te**, Miles Gloriose, quam levis sis_, which involves an instantiation of the so-called **proleptic accusative**,  is really illuminating. This construction could well be at the basis of the passive construction of the example _Quidam saepe in parva pecunia perspiciuntur quam sint leves_: i.e., its nominative subject _quidam_ could correspond to a subjacent proleptic accusative object in the active voice. Cf. this interesting example from Cicero: _nosti uirum, quam tectus_ (Cic. _Att._ 14.21.2) 'You know how cryptic the man is'. NB: _virum_ is a proleptic accusative.

Comment: @Mitomino Funny thing: I'm usually the one saying, against objections from linguists, that language sometimes works by simultaneously evoking multiple senses of words or multiple grammatical structures and blending them in some _ad hoc_ way (e.g. [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/57324/6700) on ELL). But the two sentences in this question seem to me to have an unambiguous grammatical structure, no need for unusual blending. I'll add a diagram to the answer—and google to find out what a proleptic accusative is.

Comment: Many thanks, Ben! I've just added a link to the notion of "proleptic accusative" (on the first page of the article you'll see a brief definition & a typical example).

Comment: @Mitomino: The "proleptic accusative" is something I have not encountered before--. a noun that can be both subject and object. The ex. from Cicero (Att. 14.21.2), did it come from the paper by Hilla Halla-Aho? Checking with the chaps on CHAT, Cerberus pointed me to Q: https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/4684/1982, Prolepsis is not exclusive to the accusative. If "prolepsis" is "The anticipation or representation of a thing as existing before it actually does or did so; anticipatory use of adjectives as in 'paint the town red' (Oxford), why is it called the "proleptic accusative"?

Comment: @tony The example from Cicero you mention was taken from the same source of Terentius's example above: cf. _patrem nouisti ad has res quam sit perspicax_ (Ter. Haut. 370). I can give you more bibliography on this topic, if you're interested. As for your example of "prolepsis", I think that we're not talking on the very same phenomenon. In fact, note that Latin does have cases of proleptic accusatives but lacks resultative constructions like "to paint the wall red" or "to wipe the table clean". Cf.  https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/8809/why-can-t-we-wipe-the-slate-clean-in-latin

Comment: @Mitomino: Thank you, some extra bibliography would be most welcome. The expression "to paint the town red" is so common, here, that I assumed that you would be aware of it.

Comment: @tony You can take a look at the interesting examples of proleptic accusative of this downloadable article (please see **pages 118 & 119**, examples from (44) to (47)): https://revistes.uab.cat/catJL/article/view/v16-bortolussi/208-pdf-en  At the end of this article there are some relevant references: Bortolussi (2012), Álvarez Huerta (2007), and the article you mentioned above in a comment of yours: Halla-aho (2012).